# Return Pandas DataFrame references/names to a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I've defined a function that cleans a data frame and returns a new dataframe. I have many data frames that I want to run this function on. I had a list of my DFs, `namelist=[a,b,c]` and passed them in a loop through my function. I want to return a similar list, `cleanDFs=[aClean, bClean, cClean]`. I tried to do this like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(Names)):
    c = dataCleaning(catDFs[i])
    cleanDFs.append(pd.DataFrame(c))
```

However, this makes `cleanDFs` be a list of the *contents* of each data frame, not a list of names. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
cleadDFs = [dataCleaning(d) for d in catDFs]
```